# How to use a theme package with TeXShop

Tags: texlive, texshop, themes

I have a folder structured `texmf_name/tex/latex/name/...` that contains some themes and classes etc.. Where do I put this folder / where can I set the path to this folder in TeXShop?

Im quite new to this and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: If by `Themes` you mean syntax color themes they would go in `~/Library/TeXShop/Themes` (TeXShop has the menu command `TeXShop->Open ~/Library/TeXShop` to help get you there. If that isn't what you mean please explain. If by `classes` you mean LaTeX class files you should put them in your personal texmf tree starting at `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/` (Note: `~/Library` is invisible in Finder by default; hold the `Opt` Key down and click on the `Go` menu in finder for a menu command that opens it for viewing.)

Comment: continued: The `texmf/tex/latex/` folder structure is not created by default so you'll have to go to `~/Library` and create it yourself. Finally, Your TeX Distribution will find your class and style package files automatically, TeXShop doesn't have to be configured to do anything.